# Spring Batch Auto Configuration with postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying a plain Spring batch app using PosgreSQL as the database.

pom.xml:-

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have explicitly excuded 'hsqldb' to make sure that Spring batch uses posgres. Adding this dependecy fixes the problem but I do not want to use hsqldb in my setup.

Configuration class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing   
public class Application {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    }
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: theapp
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
  profiles:
    active: local

---

spring:
  profiles: local
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      database: dbname
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/org.postgresql.Driver

---

spring:
  profiles: abc
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: dbname
      host: abc.com
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://abc.com:5432/dbname
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Junit Class:-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "local" })
public class BillingEngineBatchTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("");
    }

}
```

### PROBLEM

How to tell Spring Batch to use postgres and not the embedded database.?

During app startup I am getting an excetion saying: "Caused by: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE."`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "local" are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "local" are currently active).
```

Comment: By removing `<scope>runtime</scope>` from the dependency. As that will only include the dependency when building the deployable not when running a test.

Comment: @M.Deinum postgres:compile also didn't help.

Comment: Why do you have a specific profile and what is your `application-local.yml` look like (if you have one).

Comment: @M.Deinum - Updated question with complete application.yml. I am maintining all profile in one file itself. db (host,name) can be different for various profiles.

Comment: Your test class is wrong. Don't use `@ContextConfiguration` use `@ SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgres then you may need this in you `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I hope this can fix your problem